# (JavaFX) After maximizing the window (stage), i cant select items in the tableview anymore

Tags: javafx, tableview

since my code is quite long, I'll try to only describe the issue first to see if someone has faced it before.

I have a TableView that i populate with various objects which works just fine. I created a context menu so whenever I right-click an Item i can edit certain columns. Everything works fine but when i maximize the window, I cant select any Items anymore by clicking on them.

Has anyone faced that issue before?

Thx for the help!

edit:
I added some lines of code. Im using Java 1.8.

```
    anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
    anchorPane.setMaxWidth(550.0);

    tabPane = new TabPane();
    tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.UNAVAILABLE);
    tabPane.setTabMinHeight(22.0);
    tabPane.setPrefWidth(this.navigationWidth);

    homeTableView = new TableView<Player>();
    homeTableView.setEditable(true);
    homeTableView.setContextMenu(homeContextMenu);

    List<Player> test= mainWindow.getHomeTeamPlayer();
    ObservableList<Player> homeTeamPlayer =     FXCollections.observableArrayList(test);
    homeTableView.setItems(homeTeamPlayer);
    homeTableView.setContextMenu(homeContextMenu);

    Field[] fields = Player.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field field: fields){

        // Get column information from Metadata
        ColumnMetadata columnMetadata = field.getAnnotation(ColumnMetadata.class);

        if(!columnMetadata.showInTable()) continue;

        TableColumn<Player, String> HomeCol = new TableColumn<>(columnMetadata.displayTitle());

        HomeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(field.getName()));

        if(columnMetadata.isEditable()){
            HomeCol.setEditable(true);

        }

        homeTableView.getColumns().add(HomeCol);
    }

    homeTab = addTab("homename", homeTableView);

    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(tabPane, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(tabPane, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(tabPane, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(tabPane, 0.0);

    anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(tabPane);



    public Tab addTab(String name, TableView tableView){
    Tab tab = new Tab();
    tab.setText(name);
    tab.setContent(tableView);
    tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab);
    return tab;
    }
```

Comment: While we understand your code may be long, it'd be very helpful if you included an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question so others can externally reproduce the issue.

Comment: It's also useful to include the version of Java you are using and which platform you are running your code on.

Comment: I just figured out that this seems to be a problem with the resolution of my MacBook Pro. This error just occurs for the 1680x1050 px resolution. In any other case it works properly.